# Form validation check for empty string using red border around that particular field

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I created a function if one of the field of the form is empty it will show red border around that field and show some error text related to that field. But when there is only one field empty it shows the error perfectly but border comes along in all other fields too. So, this is problem I want the border only to come for that empty field only**

[this is the link to my code, here in this link you can I have filled three fields and last field is 
   empty and I want the red border to come for only this field not other fields][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/gurkiran/kf5m6bsa/
```

Comment: Please post your code here. Codepen might disappear at some point and then your question doesn't make any sense. You can even create a running example here. It's that <> icon over the text box. Same as codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this solution. I've changed your `border` function.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const input = document.querySelectorAll("input");

form.addEventListener("submit",e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    border();
    const firstName = form.firstName.value.trim();
    const lastName = form.lastName.value.trim();
    const email = form.email.value.trim();
    const password = form.password.value.trim();
    const nameReg = /[a-zA-Z]{3,}/;
    const emailReg =/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*/;
    
    if (firstName === "" && lastName === "" && email === "" && password === ""){
        first()
        last()
        mail()
        pass()
    } else if (lastName === "" && email === "" && password === ""){
        last();
        mail();
        pass();

    }else if ((email === "" || email === emailReg) && (password === "")){
        mail();
        pass();
    }
     else  if (firstName === ""){
         first()

    } else if (lastName === ""){
        last();
    } else if (email === ""){
         mail();
    } else if (password === ""){
        pass();
    }else{
        form.reset();
    }
})
///First Name Text
const first = () =>{
    form.firstName.placeholder = "";
}
// Last name Text
const last = () =>{
    form.lastName.placeholder ="";
}
// Email
const mail = () =>{
    form.email.placeholder = "email@example/com";
    form.email.setAttribute("class","placeholder"); 
}
//Password Text
const pass = () =>{
    form.password.placeholder ="";
}
/// Border for the input fields
const border = () =>{
    input.forEach((field)=>{
    let errorMsg = form.querySelector(`input[name="${field.name}"] ~ div.errorMessage`);
    let errorImg = form.querySelector(`input[name="${field.name}"] ~ img[alt="error"]`);
      if(field.value.trim().length <= 0) {
          field.style.border ="2px solid hsl(0, 100%, 74%)";
          errorMsg.style.display = 'block';
          errorImg.style.display = 'initial';
        } else {
          field.style.border = '';
            errorMsg.style.display = 'none';
            errorImg.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
)};
```

```css
*,
*:focus,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url(../images/bg-intro-desktop.png);
  background-color: #ff7a7a;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 33% 40%;
      grid-template-columns: 33% 40%;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.h2 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 3.2em;
}

.paragraph {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

#firstH2 {
  margin-bottom: -14px;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.firstButton {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6055a5;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.firstButton span {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

input {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #b9b6d3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #3e3c49;
}

input:focus {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #3e3c49;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.placeholder::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ff7a7a;
}

.placeholder:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #ff7a7a;
}

.placeholder::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #ff7a7a;
}

.placeholder::placeholder {
  color: #ff7a7a;
}

#greenButton {
  width: 90%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #38cc8c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px #26b577;
          box-shadow: 0px 5px #26b577;
}

#greenButton span {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#greenButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #52fab1;
}

.terms {
  color: #b9b6d3;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  text-align: center;
}

.terms span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff7a7a;
  font-weight: bold;
}

form {
  position: relative;
}

#firstImg {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
  right: 9%;
}

#secondImg {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 29%;
  right: 9%;
}

#thirdImg {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 9%;
}

#fourthImg {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 33.5%;
  right: 9%;
}

.errorMessage {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #ff7a7a;
  text-align: right;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

#firstName {
  display: none;
}

#secondName {
  display: none;
}

#third {
  display: none;
}

#fourth {
  display: none;
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.attribution a {
  color: #3e52a3;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  body {
    background-image: url(../images/bg-intro-mobile.png);
  }
  .grid {
    -ms-grid-columns: 90%;
        grid-template-columns: 90%;
  }
  .h2, .paragraph {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Intro component With Sign up Form</title>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
       <!-- 1st grid -->
        <div>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <h2 class="h2" id="firstH2">Learn to code by</h2>
          <h2 class="h2">watching others</h2><br>
          <p class="paragraph">See how experienced solve problems in real time. Watching scripted tutuorials is great, but 
            understanding how developers think is invaluable.</p>
        </div>
         <!-- 2nd grid -->
        <div>
          <div>
            <br><br>
            <button class="firstButton">Try it free 7 days <span>then $20/mo. thereafter</span></button>
            <br><br>
            <!-- box for white color -->
            <div class="box">
              <form>
                <br><br>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" id="firstImg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage" id="firstName">First Name cannot be empty</div>

                <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" id="secondImg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage" id="secondName">Last Name cannot be empty</div>

                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" id="thirdImg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage" id="third">Looks like this is not an email</div>

                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" id="fourthImg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage" id="fourth">Password cannot be empty</div>

                <button type="submit" id="greenButton"><span>CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL</span></button><br>

                <div class="terms">
                  By clicking the button you are agreeing to our <span><a href="#">Terms and Services</a></span>
                </div><br><br>
              </form>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <br><br>
  <footer>
    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
      Coded by <a href="#">Gurkiran Singh</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```